# protobuf-net-VS10.msi and V2 compatible?

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net in my .net project to use protocol buffer. The project is at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/.

Currently I installed protobuf-net-VS10.msi and it works fine in vs.net 2008. There is a "V2" implementation for download too "protobuf-net v2 r444 MS .NET only.zip". I am wondering if I can use V2 and still get the VS.net 2008 integration? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet put together the Visual Studio tooling for v2; but, since the .proto => C# generation hasn't changed, it should be usable with v2 simply by adding a reference to the protobuf-net v2 dll (downloaded separately) instead of to the protobuf-net v1 dll (included in the msi).

Comment: Thanks Marc. I replaced the dll in installation directory using the v2 dll, it doesn't seem to work since now when I save the proto file, vs.net doesn't generated cs file.

Comment: @Henry no, I didn't mean replace the file in the install directory; that would indeed confuse it. I simply meant: in your **project**, remove the reference *it* adds, and add a v2 reference instead.